# Linked Server vs. Ad Hoc (OpenRowset / OpenDatasource) Distributed Queries

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sql-server-2014

I have an application which needs to grab data from different clients' databases that reside at the client's location. So alongside their normal details such as company name, address etc, I also store the name of their DB server and the name of the database I need to interrogate.

The number of clients is currently zero. However, I expect this to grow to to around 200+ in a year's time.

I am a bit confused with which option to go with to run distributed queries:

> 1. Creating linked servers for every single client (up to 200+!)
> 2. Using an OpenDataSource() or OpenRowset() ad-hoc query within an SP that feeds in the DB server and DB name dynamically from the client
>      account table

Option 2 sounds the easiest to manage because if a client was to move their server or whatever, they just need to update their details in their account once and everything *should* work correctly.

But the reason I'm confused is because of this statement on Microsoft's site:

> OPENDATASOURCE should be used only to reference OLE DB data sources
>   that are accessed infrequently. For any data sources that will be
>   accessed more than several times, define a linked server.

The external DBs will get accessed quite frequently, with the majority of transactions being `SELECT` statements.

I'm also unsure to the security implications and which option is more tight for security. Does anyone have experience in this area and could give me some tips please?

Comment: How will you address network outages, etc?  Seems to me that you should be looking at some form of replication instead of linked server\ad-hoc queries.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth It doesn't matter if the customer's server is down – the application will just tell the user it can't connect. Using replication is something for the future. Right now its better if each client manages their own DBs on site.

Answer (score 2):

I have used both. Linked servers are typically used if a database has lookup data and is connected to often. There is nothing wrong with using dynamic opendatasource to connect to your clients machines. Be very security aware as to where, and how, you store your clients credentials. You probably should read up on encrypting passwords and usernames.

Comment: That's exactly what it does: looks up data on the customer's database about their products and sales staff. I'd have to script out the adding of a linked server everytime a new customer gets added to the main application. It would also have to update the linked server details if the customer decides to move their server. Does this sound like a feasible thing to do?

Comment: Yes but make sure that you store the credentials in an secure, encrypted, fashion. Make the whole thing table driven. Don't start maintaining an ever increasing script. It can take a few hours of careful development but its worth it.

Comment: Say if I wanted to copy across data from each of the linked servers in turn, would I have to use a cursor to loop through all the linked servers and doing a `SELECT * FROM...` ?

Comment: You don't have to use a cursor but you will have to do  row by row sp_executesql. Please verify, with one server, that you can use dynamic SQL on opensource.